# Plotting RegionIntersection

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, boolean-computation, intersection

A new feature added in Mathematica 11.2 gives the ability to easily plot region intersection (see [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/09/14/its-another-impressive-release-launching-version-11-2-today/#3D%20Computational%20Geometry) post, scroll down to `3D Computational Geometry`).
[image]

However, I can't seem to understand how to find the intersection of following objects:

```
contourRegionPlot3D[region_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
    opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{reg, preds},
    reg = LogicalExpand[region && x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
    preds = Union@Cases[reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
    Show @ Table[ContourPlot3D[
        Evaluate[Equal @@ p], {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 
        RegionFunction -> Function @@ {{x, y, z}, Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]},
        opts], {p, preds}]]

shift = {1.2, 1, 1};
heart = ImplicitRegion[((y - shift[[1]])^2 + (9 (x - shift[[2]])^2)/ 4 + (z -
    shift[[3]])^2 - 1)^3 - (y - shift[[1]])^2 (z - shift[[3]])^3 - (9 (x -
    shift[[2]])^2 (z - shift[[3]])^3)/80 < 0, {x, y, z}];
heartPlot = RegionPlot3D[
    heart,
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-0.5, 2.5}},
    PlotPoints -> 30,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[lightBlue, Opacity[0.4]]
];
arcRegion = 1.4 < x^2 + y^2 < 1.6 && 1.4 < z < 1.6 && 1 \[Pi]/64 < ArcTan[x, y] < 27 \[Pi]/64;
arcRegionPlot =  contourRegionPlot3D[arcRegion, {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.1, 2}, {z, 1.2, 1.8}];

RegionIntersection[
    heartPlot // DiscretizeGraphics,
    arcRegionPlot // DiscretizeGraphics
]
```

And here's what I get as an output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I know that those 2 regions for sure intersect:
[image]

Comment: Without going into details, I suspect problems with the dimensionality of regions (surface vs. volume).  Do you want to treat them as volumes?

Comment: @Szabolcs, Frankly, I'm not sure. What I want is to have a nice annular tunnel cut through the heart.

Comment: I wouldn't expect much consistency in dimensionality from DiscretizeGraphics. Graphics are just for looks.  When you do an intersection then a surface and a volume are very different.  I would try RegionIntersection or RegionDifference on the ImplicitRegion objects, then use BoundaryDiscretizeRegion with explicit bounds on the result.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I've updated my question according to your suggestion. It works but produces some unwanted visual artifacts. Any ideas how to get rid of them?

Comment: Decrease MaxCellMeasure?  Try different Method values?

Comment: @Szabolcs, indeed, it fixed the final problem. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I know the region framework feels messy and unreliable. If you find clear bugs, do report them.  I suspect that they made the framework too general.  It can express too many problems, many of which are unreasonably difficult to solve.  Because of this, it is too easy to write inputs which won't evaluate, won't give a satisfactory result, or are just too slow to compute. Of course, this is just a personal opinion.

Comment: @Szabolcs, one final question: How can I show edges of the intersected region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Szabolcs's advice, here's what I could accomplish:

```
lightBlue = RGBColor[0.593454, 0.888609, 0.918547];
shift = {1.2, 1, 1};
heart = ImplicitRegion[((y - shift[[1]])^2 + (9 (x - shift[[2]])^2)/ 4 + (z -
    shift[[3]])^2 - 1)^3 - (y - shift[[1]])^2 (z - shift[[3]])^3 - (9 (x -
    shift[[2]])^2 (z - shift[[3]])^3)/80 < 0, {x, y, z}];
heartPlot = RegionPlot3D[
    heart,
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-0.5, 2.5}},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[lightBlue, Opacity[0.4]]
];
arcRegionImplicit = ImplicitRegion[1.4^2 < x^2 + y^2 < 1.6^2 && 1.4 < z < 1.6 && 0 < ArcTan[x, y] < \[Pi]/2, {x, y, z}];

Show[
    heartPlot,
    RegionPlot3D[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[heart, arcRegionImplicit], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]]
]
```

With the following result:
[image]
[image]